# jQuery Timed Event

Tags: jquery, timing

Is it possible, using jQuery, to fire off an event to set a div tag's text after n. seconds?

Thanks!
George

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
var doIt = function() {
    $("div.my").text("My message");
}
setTimeout(doIt, 3000);
```

Answer (score 15):

if you're using jQuery 1.4, you can always do:

`$(function() {
   $('#divId').delay(3000).text('New Text');
});`

Answer (score 4):

I've been using the following jQuery plugins below for this. Delay can be used with chained functions, notNow can't.

**Delay**

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/delay

```
$('#animate-this').fadeIn().delay(500).fadeOut();
```

**notNow**

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/notNow

```
$.notNow(2000, function() { 
    alert('woolsworth');
});
```

Comment: +1 I believe that the Delay plugin you mentioned is actually now part of the main jQuery library, as per my answer.